# Early 2013 MacBook Pro 15'' retina kernel panic

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, crash, kernel-panic

<sup>Copying my question from apple discussions where an answer couldn't be found.</sup>

After upgrading to 10.15 my MacBook started crashing frequently, especially when under higher load (5 or more browser tabs or a video game open) and more often when the charger is connected. Any advice on how to fix this?

If it crashes and I start the laptop again straight away I get the Apple logo with the bar going about 3/4 way through after that I get black screen with laptop still running (fans can be heard). If I let it rest for about 10 minutes it comes back on fine and can work for a long time unless, again it is put under higher load.

Also, when I brought my MacBook to the Genius Bar they said they couldn't do anything as it as a 'vintage' model now, and the guys on the
Apple web chat support implicitly recommended getting a new MacBook.

Hardware diagnostics found no faults. Issue occurs also in safe mode. The OS has been reinstalled 3 times from scratch and the issue persists

Crash report:

```
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff7fa6e965cb): GPU Panic: mux-regs 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 severity 3 WS-ready 0 switch-state 13 IG FBs 0 EG FBs 0:0 power-state 0 3D idle HDA idle system-state 0 power-level 20:20 connect-change 0 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xc0000000 0xffffff914893d000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P3/4

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8132ea2cb0 : 0xffffff802493f98b 
0xffffff8132ea2d00 : 0xffffff8024a76c15 
0xffffff8132ea2d40 : 0xffffff8024a6861e 
0xffffff8132ea2d90 : 0xffffff80248e6a40 
0xffffff8132ea2db0 : 0xffffff802493f077 
0xffffff8132ea2eb0 : 0xffffff802493f45b 
0xffffff8132ea2f00 : 0xffffff80250d2d89 
0xffffff8132ea2f70 : 0xffffff7fa6e965cb 
0xffffff8132ea2fd0 : 0xffffff7fa7c4b2f1 
0xffffff8132ea3050 : 0xffffff7fa7d1811b 
0xffffff8132ea30b0 : 0xffffff7fa7d181c8 
0xffffff8132ea30e0 : 0xffffff7fa804b91e 
0xffffff8132ea3130 : 0xffffff7fa804b6c0 
0xffffff8132ea31d0 : 0xffffff7fa8067190 
0xffffff8132ea3210 : 0xffffff7fa7dabd69 
0xffffff8132ea3240 : 0xffffff7fa7daa7ca 
0xffffff8132ea3280 : 0xffffff7fa7dabce4 
0xffffff8132ea32b0 : 0xffffff7fa7f86ea4 
0xffffff8132ea32e0 : 0xffffff7fa7f7d652 
0xffffff8132ea3380 : 0xffffff7fa7f7db66 
0xffffff8132ea33e0 : 0xffffff7fa7c61537 
0xffffff8132ea3430 : 0xffffff7fa7f824fe 
0xffffff8132ea3590 : 0xffffff7fa7f829fb 
0xffffff8132ea3620 : 0xffffff7fa7c64313 
0xffffff8132ea3650 : 0xffffff7fa7d53ce4 
0xffffff8132ea36d0 : 0xffffff7fa7d5387d 
0xffffff8132ea3700 : 0xffffff7fa7d5c403 
0xffffff8132ea3710 : 0xffffff7fa7d1524e 
0xffffff8132ea3750 : 0xffffff7fa7d14aed 
0xffffff8132ea37a0 : 0xffffff7fa7c03fe5 
0xffffff8132ea37c0 : 0xffffff7fa7c4db7a 
0xffffff8132ea37e0 : 0xffffff7fa7c4e422 
0xffffff8132ea3980 : 0xffffff7fa7c4e5e8 
0xffffff8132ea3a20 : 0xffffff7fa7be07af 
0xffffff8132ea3aa0 : 0xffffff7fa7bdffe9 
0xffffff8132ea3b00 : 0xffffff7fa7be1dd4 
0xffffff8132ea3b40 : 0xffffff7fa6e454ee 
0xffffff8132ea3bc0 : 0xffffff7fa6e3bcc8 
0xffffff8132ea3c50 : 0xffffff7fa7be2f61 
0xffffff8132ea3ca0 : 0xffffff80250151bb 
0xffffff8132ea3d00 : 0xffffff802506fab9 
0xffffff8132ea3d60 : 0xffffff8024a2613f 
0xffffff8132ea3db0 : 0xffffff80249457f8 
0xffffff8132ea3e10 : 0xffffff802491c515 
0xffffff8132ea3e70 : 0xffffff8024932f75 
0xffffff8132ea3f00 : 0xffffff8024a4eaf5 
0xffffff8132ea3fa0 : 0xffffff80248e7226 

      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(4.1.46)[6A2B57DF-D04E-3E54-A2D4-D859D0B89085]@0xffffff7fa6e87000->0xffffff7fa6e9afff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(4.1.46)[3D34FEDA-B9AE-31CE-8486-74BA3DED9084]@0xffffff7fa6e29000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[9BA2613C-A129-3EDD-8DC1-2CFF6B62B832]@0xffffff7fa54e1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[E6E855AD-A5B2-3518-A997-1384B4360708]@0xffffff7fa54f3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(558.3)[23A17FD4-B8DA-3D9D-8AC5-D05039DF41ED]@0xffffff7fa6e2c000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.1.46)[0266F94C-3545-376D-AF0F-802F6D340F1C]@0xffffff7fa6e7d000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7fa7bde000->0xffffff7fa7eb5fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[E6E855AD-A5B2-3518-A997-1384B4360708]@0xffffff7fa54f3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(558.3)[5BB372D5-4650-3EC3-B11B-CE5ECFA446BC]@0xffffff7fa786f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(558.3)[23A17FD4-B8DA-3D9D-8AC5-D05039DF41ED]@0xffffff7fa6e2c000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.1.46)[0266F94C-3545-376D-AF0F-802F6D340F1C]@0xffffff7fa6e7d000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(14.0)[D9BD5415-852D-3F99-B5D9-9E4FD7CABEEC]@0xffffff7fa7f53000->0xffffff7fa80fefff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7fa7bde000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[E6E855AD-A5B2-3518-A997-1384B4360708]@0xffffff7fa54f3000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
19A602

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Wed Sep 25 20:18:50 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.11.26~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 70EDD61F-86EE-3E1B-873F-98D909B78160
Kernel slide:     0x0000000024600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8024800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8024700000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16004403802
last loaded kext at 14750822075: >AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7fa81d4000, size 28672)
```

loaded kexts:

```
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.1.46
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.1.46
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.0f8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.1.18
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.14
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.1.46
>!AMikeyDriver  283.14
@GeForce    14.0.0
>!A!IHD4000Graphics 14.0.0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHDA  283.14
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!ABacklight    170.18
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.12
>!ASMCPDRC  1.0.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
>!A!IFramebufferCapri   14.0.0
@nvidia.NVDAStartup 14.0.0
>!AMuxControl   4.1.46
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
|IO!BUSBDFU 7.0.0f8
>!UTCKeyEventDriver 255
>!UTCKeyboard   255
>!UTCButtons    255
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.11.7
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    302
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 14.0.0
@nvidia.driver.NVDAResman   14.0.0
>DspFuncLib 283.14
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  558.3
@!AGPUWrangler  4.1.46
>!AHDA!C    283.14
|IOHDA!F    283.14
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.1.23
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.1.46
|IOGraphics!F   558.3
>!AGraphicsControl  4.1.46
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.0
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.3
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.0f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.0f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.0f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.0f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.0f8
>!UMultitouch   264
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.5.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.5
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.0.5
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.11.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.11.2
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

**EDIT**

Just to add: Hardware diagnostics found no faults. Issue occurs also in safe mode. The OS has been reinstalled 3 times from scratch and the issue persists.

Comment: You may want to let the "Geniuses" know that Vintage products are *still supported* and are not obsolete.  See:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624

Comment: Was this an in-place upgrade or a clean install of Catalina? In other words, did you wipe your drive clean before installing Catalina then do a data migration from Time Machine or did you just click upgrade and install over what was already existing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I performed a clean installation several times.. I also manually erased the disk using disk utility

Comment: Does the problem go away if you install 10.14?

Comment: How does this occur in safe mode? I mean, how are you even able to reproduce it given that I thought the discrete GPU drivers aren’t even loaded in safe mode? Also, do you mean at home hardware diagnostics checked out or Apple’s in house diagnostics when you took it in?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's laptops with discrete graphics units do not have a great track record. However, it may be that the OS you updated to has different drivers, or makes more demands on the GPU, which causes some kind of problem (a GPU panic in this case).

If one clean install doesn't fix it, then don't do another. You could try reinstalling the previous OS: if everything works, then stay on that OS for the remainder of this laptop's life. If it doesn't, then you know it's not the software, and age or misfortune has caused some hardware problem.

Fixing hardware problems will not be cheap, and I would recommend putting that money towards a newer Mac instead. 8 years is not a bad innings for a laptop.